# Prevent UIPanGesture from offscreen and go out the bounds of its parent view - iOS

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I guess its duplicated question, but I have checked all the info about that on stackoverflow and I'm not able to figure it out.

After `zooming` in the Image of a `UICollectionViewCell`, I want to pan the Image, but only until the borders of the `UIScreen`/parent view.

This is what's happening:

[image]

This is the code I use for `Scaling` & `Pan`:

```
- (void)moveImage:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    if (self.pinchGesture.scale<1.0){
        return;
    }

    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan || recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {

        CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.superview];

        CGPoint newcenter = CGPointMake(self.center.x + translation.x, self.center.y + translation.y);

         [self setCenter:newcenter];
         [recognizer setTranslation:CGPointZero inView:self];      
    }

}


- (void)doPinch:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{ 
    if([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan) {

        previousScale = 1.0;

    }

    CGFloat currentScale = [[self.layer valueForKeyPath:@"transform.scale"] floatValue];

    // Constants to adjust the max/min values of zoom
    const CGFloat kMaxScale = 4.0;
    const CGFloat kMinScale = 1.0;

    CGFloat newScale = 1 -  (previousScale - [gesture scale]); // new scale is in the range (0-1)
    newScale = MIN(newScale, kMaxScale / currentScale);
    newScale = MAX(newScale, kMinScale / currentScale);

    self.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(self.transform, newScale, newScale);

}
```

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Why are you using pan and pinch gesture recognizers? Why not have a scrollview in the cell, and add an image view inside it, for zooming and panning? All this is done automatically for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just going to try this approach!!

Comment: I figure it out! It's working. I post the code I used. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I use the zoom that implements `UIScrollView`. I added a `UIScrollView` to my `UICollectionViewCell`.

And I've set it up the `minimumZoomScale`, `maximumZoomScale`, `zoomScale` of the `UIScrollView`, and implemented the `viewForZoomingInScrollView` `UIScrollViewDelegate` method on my Custom `UICollectionViewCell`, to get running the `zoom` functionality in the `UIScrollView`.

That's how looks the `cellForItemAtIndexPath`: method of my `UICollectionView`:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{


    SBQPhotosDetailCollectionViewCell *cell = [self.collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.imageDetail=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    cell.imageDetail.contentMode=UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    cell.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(cell.imageDetail.frame.size.width, cell.imageDetail.frame.size.height);

;
    cell.imageDetail.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

    cell.scrollView.delegate=cell;
    cell.scrollView.maximumZoomScale=4.0;
    cell.scrollView.minimumZoomScale=1.0;
    cell.scrollView.zoomScale=1.0;
    [cell.scrollView addSubview:cell.imageDetail];
    [cell.imageDetail setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[self.arrayURLS objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
                     placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"thunder"]];

    cell.delegate = self;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: It says that I can't accept my own answer as correct until 2 days. So I wait ;)